# Confusion about Fubini's theorem and when it does or doesn't apply

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration, multiple-integral, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I've been reading into Fubini's theorem (rectangular regions) quite extensively over the last few days, and I've gathered the following:

1. For Fubini's theorem to apply, the function must be Lebesgue integrable - that is, the integral of the absolute value of the function over the rectangle must be finite, and the function must be measurable (though practically any function that can be described is measurable).

   2. All Riemann integrable functions are Lebesgue integrable except for conditionally convergent improper Riemann integrals.

So, how does Fubini's theorem work for these conditionally convergent improper Riemann integrals? Can you or can you not switch the order of integration?

Also, if you were integrating over a rectangle which was infinite in one or both dimensions, is that still a rectangle and does Fubini's theorem for rectangular regions still apply?

And lastly, how does Fubini's theorem for improper integrals tie into all this?

Thanks.

PS: I'm quite new to all this and I'm struggling to piece all the different strands together. I have no knowledge of measure theory, so I would appreciate an answer in simpler terms.

Comment: *Note:* Fubinis theorem doesn't require rectangles, but only $\sigma$-finite spaces, which e.g. include $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Why are you asking measure theory questions without having studied measure theory? The questions you ask are very technical and will need measure theoretic formulation to answer.

Comment: @ε-δ Well I'm reviewing multivariable calculus right now, and most textbooks on the topic just say that the region has to be continuous (for Fubini's theorem) and leave it at that. I wasn't too satisfied with this and have been trying to understand more about when I can or cannot apply Fubini's theorem without delving into measure theory. I've made quite a bit of progress, but things aren't all tying together at the moment for me.

Comment: @ε-δ I'm trying to be as comprehensive as I can with my understanding of Fubini's theorem. The bit about improper integrals in the couple of questions I've asked above are the last pieces of information I need to know for the puzzle to fit together so to speak. Is there any way to answer them in simple terms?